# Как ускорить перебор элементов массива

Tags: pascal, delphi, алгоритм

Нельзя ли как-то эту часть программы записать в одном цикле? не получается, чтобы выводилось правильно?

```
for i:=1 to n do begin a[i]:=random(21)-10; write(a[i]:6); end; writeln;
for i:=1 to n do begin b[i]:=random(21)-10; write(b[i]:6); end;
for i:=1 to n do begin if a[i]>b[i] then c[i]:=a[i] else c[i]:=b[i];end;writeln;
for i:=1 to n do begin write(c[i]:6); end;
```

**Обновление**

Полный листинг:

```
const K=100;
var 
  a,b,c:array[1..K] of integer;
  n,i:integer;
begin
  writeln('введи размерности массивов');
  readln(n);
  randomize;
  for i:=1 to n do begin a[i]:=random(21)-10; write(a[i]:6); end; writeln;
  for i:=1 to n do begin b[i]:=random(21)-10; write(b[i]:6); end;
  for i:=1 to n do begin if a[i]>b[i] then c[i]:=a[i] else c[i]:=b[i];end;writeln;
  for i:=1 to n do begin write(c[i]:6); end;
end.
```

Comment: @Ekaterina: Записать все циклы в один — это наверное хорошая идея. Но не думайте, что вы от этого получите какое-то «ускорение». Одна наносекунда, выигранная снижением расходов на управление циклами, ничто по сравнению с десятками, а то и сотнями миллисекунд, расходуемых каждой из операций вывода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, к сожалению ничего тут нельзя сделать. Цикл будет выводить по очереди массивы a, b и проверять условие.
Ps. я надеюсь, что используется в начале программы randomize?

Comment: полный текст
const K=100;
var 
  a,b,c:array[1..K] of integer;
  n,i:integer;
begin
  writeln('введи размерности массивов');
  readln(n);
  randomize;
  for i:=1 to n do begin a[i]:=random(21)-10; write(a[i]:6); end; writeln;
  for i:=1 to n do begin b[i]:=random(21)-10; write(b[i]:6); end;
  for i:=1 to n do begin if a[i]>b[i] then c[i]:=a[i] else c[i]:=b[i];end;writeln;
  for i:=1 to n do begin write(c[i]:6); end;
end.

Comment: ну все, тогда больше нечего менять. конечно можно прописать говорящие переменные, но они не особо нужны ;-)

Comment: ответ, разумеется, неверный. достаточно одного цикла. hint: в метках delphi, а не какой-то turbo pascal 5.0 (да и в нем тоже реализуемо).